# Replace text of link with link href value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to replace text of a link with link href value.

I have 1000 links in table like this.

html

```
<td  valign="middle"class="link2"align="left" width="auto" >
<a href="http://www.example1.com" target="_blank">Item1</a>
</td>
<td  valign="middle"class="link2"align="left" width="auto" >
<a href="http://www.example2.com" target="_blank">Item2</a>
</td>
.
.
.
.
```

I want to replace text value `Item1 Item2 ...` with link href value `http://www.example1.com http://www.example1.com ...`

I am trying this way but its not working.

jquery

```
$('.link2 a').html($(this).attr('href'));
//also tried like this.
$('.link2 a').html(this.attr('href'));

$('.link2 a').text($(this).attr('href'));
//also tried like this.
$('.link2 a').text(this.attr('href'));
```

Please suggest way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use callback function of html(), i.e. [.html( function )](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) or [.text( function )](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p25Sa/1/)**

```
$('.link2 a').html(function(){
   return this.href;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `this` is not refering to anchor. Loop through each anchor node and set its text.  Try with this code

```
 $('.link2 a').each(function(){
   $(this).text($(this).attr('href'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You need to iterate each anchor tag as you need to read each anchor tag `href` value and set it as its text.

```
$('.link2 a').each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('.link2 a').each(function(){
  $(this).html($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.link2').each(
 function(index)
 {
   $(this).children(":first").text($(this).attr('href'));
 }


);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.link2 a').each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy use below code

```
    $('.link2 a').each(function(){
   $(this).text($(this).attr('href'));
 });
```